# Ubuntu 22.04 vm stuck on boot at recovering journal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, proxmox

I have an ubuntu 22.04 server running on proxmox. I use it to stream media and it randomly froze up the other day. I have tried resetting and at first it would get to the login screen but freeze within a few seconds. I was also able to get to the terminal via recovery mode. But now it just gets stuck "Recovering journal" with no progress. Searching suggests booting from usb and running fsck. Issue is booting from usb still gets stuck with:

[image]